# using add_action for a header hook that has an additional parameter

Tags: php, theme-development, hooks

The theme I'm using has a hook inside `header.php` file to separate the header into two parts, left & right. I want to add some content into the right section but I don't understand how can I add the additional parameter when using `add_action()`. Code as below,

```
do_action( 'sinatra_header_widget_location', 'left' );
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/logo' );
            do_action( 'sinatra_header_widget_location', 'right' );
```

How can I pass `'right'` parameter into add_action? my funcions.php looks like:

```
add_action('sinatra_header_widget_location', 'my_custom_function');
function my_custom_function() {
    echo 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I pass 'right' parameter into `add_action`?

*In short:* You don't pass 'left' or 'right' itself to `add_action()`, but you can make the parameter be available in your callback by using the fourth parameter for `add_action()`. See examples below.

---

So despite you may already know this, a hook is a specific place in a block of (PHP) code where custom functions like yours (`my_custom_function()`) can do a certain action like displaying a custom text, or maybe perform some database inserts.

And you can make that possible by using [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) to register your callback/function which then WordPress will call via [`do_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/). I.e. `add_action()` registers a callback for running an *action* on a hook, whereas `do_action()` calls the callback that runs the action.

And there are different ways of calling `add_action()` and `do_action()`, but the basic ones are:

- `do_action()`:

  ```php
  // This hook has just one parameter.
  do_action( 'hook name', $param );

  // But this one has two parameters.
  do_action( 'hook name', $param, $param2 );

  // And a hook can have as many parameters as necessary.
  do_action( 'hook name', $param, $param2, $param3, ... );
  ```
- `add_action()`:

  ```php
  // This means the callback will receive just one parameter,
  add_action( 'hook name', 'function_name' );
  // and it's equivalent to:
  add_action( 'hook name', 'function_name', 10, 1 );

  // And same goes with this; but the priority is 9 - the default is 10,
  add_action( 'hook name', 'function_name', 9 );
  // and it's equivalent to:
  add_action( 'hook name', 'function_name', 9, 1 );

  // And this one, it uses the default priority, but accepts 2 parameters.
  add_action( 'hook name', 'function_name', 10, 2 );
  ```

So in your case, these `do_action()` calls:

```php
do_action( 'sinatra_header_widget_location', 'left' );
do_action( 'sinatra_header_widget_location', 'right' );
```

.. are identical to the first `do_action()` example above, which means the hook (`sinatra_header_widget_location`) has just one parameter, whereby the value is either `left` or `right`.

And by default, when WordPress — via `do_action()` — calls callbacks registered to a hook, they will always receive the *first* parameter passed by the hook to `do_action()`.

So you just need to make sure that your function *accepts* that first parameter.

( And the 2nd, 3rd, etc. parameters if there were any and that you wanted to access them from your callback. )

So for example, you can name it `$position` and do a conditional to check whether the value is `left` or `right`, because the `sinatra_header_widget_location` hook is being called twice — one with `left` being the value of the first (and only) parameter, and the other being `right`:

```php
function my_custom_function( $position ) {
    if ( 'right' === $position ) {
        echo 'yay, it\'s "right"';
    }
}
```

So I hope this revised answer helps you *more* :), and be sure to check the documentation for `add_action()` and `do_action()` because you'll find more information there, including user-contributed notes/examples that can assist you in using the functions (the proper way):

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/

Comment: Thanks it really worked. Should I also include `$position` inside the `add_action()` as a parameter?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. See the revised the answer, which I hope is more helpful. :)